# Blender ignores SHIFT+MMB (panning) after switching to another window?

Tags: interface, settings

So this is not a major problem, but it is an issue that gets pretty annoying. Whenever I'm using Blender and I need to switch to another window or application on my PC (to pause a video, look something up, send an email, etc), It always ignores me initially whenever I want to <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> (panning).

It only ignores the initial keyboard command, and I can pan around my scene just fine after that— but it is still extremely annoying.

Is there a fix for this? Or something in the settings to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go back to blender, the 'active window' is still on the other window so all keyboard commands will go to that one. Which is why it works on the second try(the active Window becomes blender) A good way is to <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> to blender instead.